# Selenium opens FireFox, but types in no URL

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox

I previously (about 3-5 months ago) had this working, but now it is failing. I am I not sure why. My searches so far have been fruitless. I am trying to use Cucumber to open up a web browser, and visit a web page.

Cucumber is able to open up FireFox, but types in no URL. It times out after 60 seconds and my test fails.

My setup is very simple. In my director, I have a Gemfile that only contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53.4'
```

A Gemfile.lock and a features folder. Inside the features folder is my .feature file, my step definitions folder, and my support folder. I am happy to provide any more relevant information.

---

VERSIONS

FireFox: 53.0.3 (64-bit)

Selenium: 2.53.4 (Also tried 3.4.0)

Ruby: 2.4.0

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: for Firefox 53.0 Gecko driver is mandatory... Download the latest driver and try

Comment: For future references or question please do provide part of the code that you find to be the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a mismatch in the selenium webdriver you are using and the firefox browser version. Use the latest selenium webdriver. The problem should get fixed.